# how to Open new screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, android-intent

i am new to android and i have created a login page after verifing login

i get results true or false on the bases of user authentication now my goal is to show another screen on successful authentication with some new textboxes and button i mean new layout how to achieve this???

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Umma put more appropriate tags for more viewers who have ability to answer you, who search Questions by tag. Tag: android would have brought you more answers.

Comment: This is a good and easy way to add activities to your project
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to [start new activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities). You can read more on initiating new Activities at [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask).

However you might consider making a "normal" application screen and call another Activity for login purposes instead of having a login page and redirection.

So if page/Activity_A requires user to be logged in, you call *LoginActivity* with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and get true/false if user has properly logged in.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/

Answer (score 2):

create an Intent and pass the intent to startactivty method. ake sure your activity should be defined in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Read about **Intents**

intents are used to start new activity

Activity is the super class that represents each of your view
corresponding to your layout

in Professional Android App Dev- WROX by Retro Meier
gives good examples for this in a chapter for Intents and Broadcast.