# How To Add Second Activity In Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Hey everyone! Im trying to add a second activity to my android project, but im not sure how to add the activity files exactly?

Ive added a class here "Name/Scr/PackageName/MyClassHere" but Im not sure if that the correct thing to do or place to put it, because there isnt a XML file either.

Im using this code to open a new screen, http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html And I get 2 error's. 
1 at runtimeon this line: 
`Intent i = new Intent(Coinparison.this, ResultsScreen.class);`
it says it cant find my activity.

And the other error here `setContentView(R.layout.ResultsScreen);` which says "ResultsScreen" cannot be resolved.

Not sure whats wrong, but any help is great! :)

Comment: Have you declared your activity in the manifest? Do you have an XML file for your layout?

Comment: I dont have a xml file for the new class, but yes i declared it in the AndroidManifest like so,  <activity android:name=".ResultsScreen" android:label="ResultsScreen">

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a wizard in eclipse now for adding activities, just right click on your project, go to new -> other -> android -> Android Activity

This will create the class, layout and manifest entry.

Answer (score 17):

Add your activity to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="ResultsScreen"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think u need add this activity in manifest file like this

```
 <application  balblabla>
        <activity android:name=".firstActivity">
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
             //bla bla bla
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".secondActivity"/>

    </application>
```

see  link again and find this : //AndroidManifest.xml
there u can see  text which writed in bold mode

```
<activity class=".Screen2" android:label="Screen 2">
      </activity>
```

Comment: Ok I think got it working, I had the activity placed in wrong spot inside the Manifest file. But now how do I add buttons and ect. to my new activity? Do I create another xml?

Comment: Nvm I got it working with this tutorial! http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/

Comment: yes, just create new xml file (for example secondActivity.xml ) and work with him as with first . .

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Error in """ `setContentView(R.layout.ResultsScreen);` which says "*`ResultsScreen`*" cannot be resolved """

Go to **`second.java`** (Related to second activity) file and import missing classes.

**In Eclipse, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to import missing classes (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> on Mac).**