# Android Eclipse Add New Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I am using Win 7.0, Eclipse and android SDK. I want to add new activity in  AndroidManifest.xml Application tab as it is shown in this tutorial [Android Development – Adding Screens & Button Handlers](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-adding-screens-button-handlers/)

I add an Activity name to my manifest but it does not automatically turn it into a link. e.g. I cannot click the "Name"(It is not a hyperlink as shown in the article), thus I cannot create my class.

Can You Help me? what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you please clean up your question and provide the suspect code from your `AndroidManifest.xml`? It's very difficult to determine what you need.

Comment: Confusing question. I think I understood the general problem (add a new activity, I guess), but I have no idea if it's in the manifest (only?), what is the problem in the manifest, and if you added the java file already. Improve your communications skills/eloquence a bit, if you can.

Comment: Please look this image http://94.78.74.150/aa.jpg , you see red arrow to show Name as UNLink

Comment: @atromgame Now, with that picture, it makes less sense... what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You have to create a class that extends Activity first, then you can add it to your manifest.

Comment: @DDoSAttack, please look this image too, http://94.78.74.150/bb.jpg

Comment: @DDoSAttack , Orginal image form   http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-adding-screens-button-handlers/

Comment: Did you see what I am saying, in my Eclipse , Name is not Clickable, But other image (bb.jpg) clicable and when you click on it Eclipse create automatic the class and OnCreate functions

Comment: BTW for the record... That is REALLY bad tutorial!!! Whoever made that really needs to learn standard OOP practices and how to properly program for Android... who the hell names their class "screen1"[sic]??? and even worse, who names an Android Activity "main"[sic]???

Comment: That tutorial even says to create the class first.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I dont understand why looking unlink in my ecplise. May be diffrent eclipse or android version. I hope that you understand me.

Comment: That is odd. Try reinstalling the ADT plugin?

Comment: It's definitely a different version of the ADT plugin. You have a field "VM Safe Mode" and "Restore Any Version" which aren't in the bb screenshot, nor on my screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to add Activity to an Android project in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

1.Go to the `Androidmanifest.xml` file and add the activity inside the  tag
if your activity name is secondAct.

2.Create a class named `secondAct`.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Project1Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".secondAct"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".third"></activity>
    </application>
```

3 . if you are using a button for going to next activity, use the following code in `secondAct.java`

```
Button fbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sbtn);
        fbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent sec=new Intent(secondAct.this,com.asish.third.class);
                startActivity(sec);

            }
        });
```

Comment: hi i saw your image , in the image below there is a last tab named Androidmanifest.xml, where you can add the above xml code.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the small tab underneath that says AndroidManifest.xml and shows you the XML code for it. It should look like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name=".ApplicationName"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

Okay, click on ADD, then select the top box that says "Create a new element at the top level, in Application" and then you should get a box with linkable NAME*.

Comment: not with code, I want to automatic create class, Please look this image http://94.78.74.150/aa.jpg , you see red arrow , Name is not LINK

Comment: Have you made the class yet? It won't make the class for you.

Comment: Please look this image too http://94.78.74.150/bb.jpg, As you see, Name is clickable , but first image( aa.jpg) Name is not clicable, When you click Name , eclipse open Class windows and its create class and oncreate function, Did you understand me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the class first, then point to that class in your manifest... just putting the class name in the manifest is not enough. It will not automatically create it for you.

Also, it is easier to create the class first because then Eclipse will autocomplete the class name/path for you.

EDIT: AH HAH! I see what link you are talking about...
Yeah, you need to actually create the class first for that to appear.

Comment: No I see internet eclipse create automatic class and Oncreate function, Please look http://94.78.74.150/aa.jpg , you see red arrow then NOT clickable, NOT Link, but I see on internet that the NAME is LİNK and eclipse create automatic the activity class and function

Comment: That is not correct... you need to go to "File">"New">"Class" then extend Activity and it will automatically create the proper class with the onCreate() method. THEN you go to the manifest and put the Activity in there.