# ANDROID How to get visual editor for the nwe Acitivity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a new Activity through androidManifest.xml as it was described here: [Best way to add Activity to an Android project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse)

I hava a class DrugieOkno and I run it from the MainActivity by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DrugieOkno.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**but I would like to be able to design it in the way I designed the MainActivity window. What I suppose to do to have Access to Graphical Layout of the DrugieOkno (this additional Activity)
I work in the Eclipse.**

Comment: Did you create a layout for the new activity?

Comment: If i had i wouldn't ask. The only thing I had done is what I wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a layout for the `Activity` you created.

- Select res/layout
- Right click, New > Other
- Select Android XML Layout File, Next
- The dialog will let you fill in some basics.
- Go to the `Activity` class you made and put `setContentView(R.layout.LAYOUT_FILE_NAME);` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @RobertKilar: In the project tree. Under the project name, there will be src, gen, some others, and res.

Comment: sorry, but I don't have any available R.layout beside activity main, I would like to create another one.

Comment: @RobertKilar: After making the layout file, R should be regenerated to include the new layout.

Comment: Ok so that's my question really. How to generate new Layout file and include it into project so I can connect it with my DrugieOkno(second Activity)

Comment: @RobertKilar: The instructions I gave will do that for you.