# Android retrieving info form a another activity, creating new layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I am learning how to develop under Android. I've made a new project, main activity, and I wanted to design a new window. I've genereted the new Activty as it it described here
[Best way to add Activity to an Android project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse)

1. But i can't get the visual editor for that new activity. I know that I suppose to create new layout but how to do it and connect it with that second Activity?
2. How to properly go back from the secondActivity(close it? minimize it? how?) to the mainActivity and don't loose information gathered why we were using secondActivity(for example what options user has made?

This is how i invoke the second Acitivity and it works fine.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DrugieOkno.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1:
[Here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/03/tutorial-how-to-start-a-new-activity/) is a basic tutorial on how to create a new `Activity`. For a more comprehensive one containing more information about Android development you can see [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html).

For question 2:
For tansfering data between `Activities` [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html) is a nice tutorial.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. To add a new activity, follow the methods answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse) question. This way you will create a new activity without adding it to the Manifest manually. [every activity needs to be listed in the `AndroidManifest.xml`].

Say you create a new activity names `Activity2.java`. To add the new layout to the new activity, add a new xml file to `res/layout` folder, say `activity2.xml` [where you define your new activity's layout]

To link the new layout to the new activity, include this line in your newly created `Activity2.java`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
```

So it will look like this:

```
    public class Activity2 extends Activity{

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity2);         
    }       
  }
```

2 . Now if you want to send some data from your `Activity1.java` to `Activity2.java`, you need to use `Bundles`.

So, if you want to send say a `String` from `Activity1`, do the following in `Activity1.java`:

```
Intent nextActivity = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
Bundle passData = new Bundle(); //to hold your data
passDataBndl.putString("fname", fname); //put in some String. the first parameter to it is the id, and the second parameter is the value
nextActivity.putExtras(passDataBndl); //Add bundle to the Intent
startActivityForResult(nextActivity, 0); //Start Intent
```

To recieve data in your `Activity2.java` do the following (say, `onCreate()`)

```
 Bundle params = this.getIntent().getExtras(); //gets the data from the Intent
 String firstName = params.getString("fname"); //gets value of fname
```