# Eclipse removing activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide, android-manifest

Added new activity via:   [Best way to add Activity to an Android project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse)

Soon the new activity added in AndroidManifest.xml is gone?

How do I fix this?

Thank You.

Comment: I had the same problem a while back. I just re-added the activity into the manifest and it was fine. I'm not sure whether there is a legitimate reason for this or whether it is a bug.

Comment: @edwoollard: this is the 3rd time I added it back...guess do a restart of the IDE?

Comment: normally running the emulator shouldnt change anything on manifest file.. are you on eclipse juno and latest ADT?

Comment: @Paschalis: yeah, not sure if it a result of the emulator, I think it is also happening after any other code changes.

Comment: @Paschalis: not sure about the "Juno". I am running Eclipse with the android plug in: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: Juno is the latest version of Eclipse, Indigo is before that and is what you have. Just to clarify that for you, Greg.

Comment: @edwoollard: thanks, newbie here

Comment: so try updating your eclipse, and your ADT. ADT for eclipse was buggy, and may still is. You can always edit manifest xml file directly from XML code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you using? this happened with me while am using Mac OS, the `AndroidManifest.xml` was `Read` only, so I needed to change it to `Read/Write`

Comment: Windows 7, I'll check that thanks. Also, notice there are 2 manifest files, the one to modify is the "bin/", right?

Comment: you should not have 2 Manifest files. there should be one only, in project directory.

Comment: Ignore the bin folder, its a result of building the project.

Comment: what is the project path you use, like `C:/projects/hello_project`