# How to create a new activity in an android project without creating it under an example folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Whenever I create a new android activity in eclipse using Mac the activity is created under an example folder. Like src.com.example. What I would like to do is create an activity under a pre-existing folder. like src.com.already_created_folder. How would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: you want to change the activity's folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score -2):

You can just copy the source files (by selecting them, and hitting command_c, then paste them in your other created folder.

A better alternative would probably be to just rename the folder to the name you would like.  To do this:

1. right click on the folder you are wanting to rename
2. select 'refactor'
3. select 'rename'

Comment: I've tried just moving the activity to another folder but when I do this it does not recognize R anymore like when I use findViewById(R.id.some_id); there is an error for R.

Comment: Then use the second method I recommended (the 'Refactor' menu).  And then you should do a 'clean' compile.