# Eclipse create android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying create an android application like this : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

But when I create the application the src folder is empty.Here you can see:http://prntscr.com/3xm25c

And also I have one more question:Should I select the api level 23(Android L) or 19 (Kitkat) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new activity.
To do this,

> Right click *src* folder -> new -> other -> Android -> Android Activity

For more you can look at this SO question : [Best way to add Activity to an Android project in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse)
or this Blog post: [How to create a new activity in Android?](http://www.javabeat.net/create-new-activity-android/)

Comment: I can't see this option ?

Answer (score 0):

The API of the project is consisting of what version of android you are targetting. If you want to optimize and running it Android 4.4 you have to choose 19. I think that 23 is the newest one and if you want to develop for Android L with Material Design you have to make some updates. Check that [Link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html) - it's describing Android APIs.