# src + Layout no longer auto generated in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have had to install a new Eclipse and SDK on a new computer however I have come into trouble when creating a project.

When I try to create a project i.e. Tabbed Activity - NO src and layout files (i.e. MainActivity) are being auto generated.

I have tried the following steps to try and resolve this issue

1. Reinstalled Eclipse several times
2. Installed the new software - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I believe this is meant to be a bug with the new update but are there any ways around this?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: I have seen some users having same issue. Haven't updated mine yet. May be the team just decided it's no longer needed. Or may be an update fixes the issue.

Comment: Indeed, however you still cannot create an activity manually. Hopefully Eclipse fixes the issue quickly

Comment: This bug has been running through SO since morning today -- guess the update needs an update and hope its done sooner.

Comment: Isn't the right click in SRC folder -> new  -> other -> Android Activity method working?

Comment: Nope, I cant even manually do it

Comment: Well, appears to be serious issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, someone else asked the same question here : [Eclipse create android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475276/eclipse-create-android-application)
and the right click in SRC folder -> new -> other -> Android Activity method seems working for him.

Another way would be manually creating the classes and layout files and registering them in manifest, which you claim isn't working.

Creating Activity through manifest is working for some people as well.

Another obvious solution, create the classes and layout files using a file explorer and a text editor outside eclipse, of course in your project folder, and refresh the folder inside eclipse.

These are some workarounds you may try out until they release a fixed version.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Empty Activity rather than Blank activity