# After updating ADT to version 23 there are some problems with the tool

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

Recently updated my ADT to version 23 
but there are some problems 
After creating project the activity is empty and source also empty . 
What is the problem how o resolve this ???
Thnaks in advance

Comment: There's a bug with the new ADT I think. Why not go ahead and create the files yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives to try until the issue is fixed.

In eclipse, create new android application and then right click in the src folder -> new -> other -> Android Activity.

Another way would be manually creating the classes and layout files and registering them in manifest.

Creating Activity through manifest.

Another obvious solution, create the classes and layout files using a file explorer and a text editor outside eclipse, of course in your project folder, and refresh the folder inside eclipse.

I have answered the same question here:
[src + Layout no longer auto generated in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478186/src-layout-no-longer-auto-generated-in-eclipse)

Comment: @abishek: created class and activity under that tab , but how to import the gen[Generated java files]

Comment: Have you created the class files using first method in the SRC folder or the second?

Comment: Under src folder created the class file
Under the layout folder created the activity

Comment: I am not getting you, but may be cleaning the project fixes the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56569/discussion-between-abhishek-verma-and-user3251646).