# Android - onClick open new window

Tags: android, android-studio, buttonclick

I've started a bit with android development, and for my first assigment I've decided to make soundboard. Ive successfully added several buttons, and they make a sound on click.
Currently when you open application it directly opens Animal Soundboard.

What I want to do next is:
When you start application that it offers you:

Animal Sounds
Laugh Sounds
etc...

When you click on some of them, so it opens Animal sounds?

Basically I need help with how to code when you click on button that opens new windows with new buttons.

Comment: This site is for specific problems only, not all-in-one solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736571/using-intent-in-an-android-application-to-show-another-activity

Comment: First thing you have to do is go through this http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: I'm so sorry, I did research but it didn't gave me what I needed.

Only thing I needed was how to start new activity (open new window)
but I explained entire situation so you guys know what I'm building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link should be useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337874/best-way-to-add-activity-to-an-android-project-in-eclipse)

You want to create Activity and start it after button click

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} 
});
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, how to start new activity!

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the Windows you are referring to are called Activities( or Fragments, in some scenarios).
On a button click, you can launch a new Activity using Intents.

You can learn how to do that here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html